# How to generate a correct HTTP response for a pbf within AWS API Gateway?

Tags: postgis, mapbox, vector-tiles, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am attempting to implement this approach to serving vector tiles from PostGIS using a lambda function and an AWS API Gateway Method: https://www.sparkgeo.com/blog/vector-tile-server-using-postgis. And for the most part, I have it working.

But it doesn't seem to be in the correct format and not a usable vector tile. this is what I am getting back:

[image]

And this is what I receive back from https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2/13/1310/3168.vector.pbf
[image]

I tried switching the content type to application/x-protobuf, but that had no effect.  I think I need to do something additional to the byte array to make it into a consumable vector tile but the blog post was light on details regarding the API Gateway.

But this is what I have setup: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was, after many hours, finally able to work out something that works between the AWS API Gateway and the lambda function.

**First**, I changed the [sparkgeo index.js](https://www.sparkgeo.com/blog/vector-tile-server-using-postgis) callback call from:

```
        var s = b.toString('base64');
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            body: s,
            isBase64Encoded: true
        });
```

to

```
var s = b.toString('base64');
callback(null,s);
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667160/386619
>   I found out that if you set Content handling to Convert to binary
>   (CONVERT_TO_BINARY) the entire response has to be base64

Then I had to configure the HTTP Get Method as:

**Full Method:** 
[image]

**Method Request**
[image]

**Integration Request**
[image]

**Integration Response**
[image]

**Method Response**
[image]

And then over in the API Settings, add `application/octet-stream` to  **Binary Media Types**:
[image]

And the full method Json definition is:

```
{
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "authorizationType": "NONE",
    "apiKeyRequired": false,
    "requestParameters": {
        "method.request.path.dataset": true,
        "method.request.path.x": true,
        "method.request.path.y": true,
        "method.request.path.z": true
    },
    "methodResponses": {
        "200": {
            "statusCode": "200",
            "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Content-Type": false
            },
            "responseModels": {
                "application/octet-stream": "Empty"
            }
        }
    },
    "methodIntegration": {
        "type": "AWS",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:795830580453:function:mvt_xxxxxxxxxxx/invocations",
        "requestParameters": {
            "integration.request.path.dataset": "method.request.path.dataset",
            "integration.request.path.x": "method.request.path.x",
            "integration.request.path.y": "method.request.path.y",
            "integration.request.path.z": "method.request.path.z"
        },
        "requestTemplates": {
            "application/json": "##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html\n##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload\n#set($allParams = $input.params())\n{\n\"body-json\" : $input.json('$'),\n\"params\" : {\n#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())\n    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))\n\"$type\" : {\n    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())\n    \"$paramName\" : \"$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))\"\n        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end\n    #end\n}\n    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end\n#end\n},\n\"stage-variables\" : {\n#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())\n\"$key\" : \"$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))\"\n    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end\n#end\n},\n\"context\" : {\n    \"account-id\" : \"$context.identity.accountId\",\n    \"api-id\" : \"$context.apiId\",\n    \"api-key\" : \"$context.identity.apiKey\",\n    \"authorizer-principal-id\" : \"$context.authorizer.principalId\",\n    \"caller\" : \"$context.identity.caller\",\n    \"cognito-authentication-provider\" : \"$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider\",\n    \"cognito-authentication-type\" : \"$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType\",\n    \"cognito-identity-id\" : \"$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId\",\n    \"cognito-identity-pool-id\" : \"$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId\",\n    \"http-method\" : \"$context.httpMethod\",\n    \"stage\" : \"$context.stage\",\n    \"source-ip\" : \"$context.identity.sourceIp\",\n    \"user\" : \"$context.identity.user\",\n    \"user-agent\" : \"$context.identity.userAgent\",\n    \"user-arn\" : \"$context.identity.userArn\",\n    \"request-id\" : \"$context.requestId\",\n    \"resource-id\" : \"$context.resourceId\",\n    \"resource-path\" : \"$context.resourcePath\"\n    }\n}\n"
        },
        "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
        "contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
        "timeoutInMillis": 29000,
        "cacheNamespace": "h7bei1",
        "cacheKeyParameters": [],
        "integrationResponses": {
            "200": {
                "statusCode": "200",
                "responseParameters": {
                    "method.response.header.Content-Type": "'application/octet-stream'"
                },
                "contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_BINARY"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have followed your configuration of API Gateway, but I have problem with the event.pathParameters object - it's undefined now. Don't you know where can be a problem ? Anyway thank you for the detailed documentation of it...I have followed the sparkgeo.com blog, but this is good (and necessary) addition to it.